# Consequences of violation of employment contract in India

Tags: employment, india, breach-of-contract, indian-penal-code

What legal action can an employer take against the employee who used the company laptop to work on a freelancing project? Duration maybe max of 10 days.

Possibility of allegation from employer is for using the company's asset (laptop).

If a full time employee works part time to another company in IT industry serving different domains, will that amount to dual employment in India?

**Note**: The freelancing project was just initiated as a sample project and no commitments have been made and the same wasn't being invoiced to the company who offered the work.

Comment: Was there an actual contract? did the freelance work occur during normal work hours, or detract from the employee's work output and performance? Was there a company policy against use of the laptop for non-company purposes, and if so was it communicated to the employee?

Comment: Hi @DavidSiegel - There was no contract for freelancing work. Freelancing work was done after business hours and there was no distraction in employee's performance.

As per company policy it is a violation and already employee is being interrogated.